# Помогите js ошибка

Tags: node.js

Есть такой код(объяснять нет смысла)

```
>   var nick = message.args[1];
users[message.user].nick =  
    nick.lenght < 15 ?
        users[message.user].nick = nick : users[message.nick].nick;
message.plain(
nick.lenght < 15 ?
    `Ник ${nick}, был успешно установлен!` : `Ник не может быть больше 15-ти символов!`
);
```

Выдает ошибку че-то по типу Cannot read property 'nick' or undefined

Comment: Проверьте есть ли свойство nick у метода users. Как мне кажется, нету :)

Comment: пример 
 "141798615": {
  "nick": "Никита",
  "balance": 5000
 },

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> users[message.user]
> ```

Здесь `undefined`.

> ```
> nick.lenght
> ```

Кстати, тут тоже - буквы переставь.